# How to end a program (with a function), without killing it?

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to know how I can end my program without having a tab pop up saying that I have to "kill python". I tried exit(), which works but a tab pops up and forces me to exit, which I don't want. Here is my code:

```
if (answer == "no"):
    print("okay, goodbye")
    exit()
elif (answer == "yes"):
    print("great! let's continue talking")

question2 = input("What is your favorite food? ")
```

Essentially, I want the prorgam to stop/end without actually having a message pop up after, telling me to close the tab; like I just want it to stop as if I printed a single statement. Anyways I want the program to stop when the user selects "no" because question2 is put there if the user selects "yes" but question2 still shows up after selecting "no" and not having exit() there. For a better example of what I am trying to fix, I've tried:

```
import time

if (answer == "no"):
    print("okay, goodbye")
    time.sleep(99999.9)

elif (answer == "yes"):
    print("great! let's continue talking")

question2 = input("What is your favorite food? ")
```

But I find this way kind of silly and the wrong way to do it. What function is similar to exit() such that it stops the program completely without having a tab pop up afterwards, telling me to close the tab?

Of course "answer" is not defined because I purposely didn't add that in since I don't have trouble with that matter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200629/discussion-on-question-by-con-fused-how-to-end-a-program-with-a-function-with).

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to exit a python program, other than reaching the end of the code, is with `raise SystemExit('message')` or `import sys; sys.exit('message')`.  The message is optional.  There will not be a popup window.  Since IDLE is a learning and development environment, IDLE itself will not quit.

The `quit()` and `exit()` functions are not regular built-in functions.  There are added -- maybe -- by the site module.  They are only intended for interactive use at a '>>>' prompt.  In regular interactive python, the effect is to unconditionally exit python.  In IDLE, user are asked if they really mean to kill the shell window.  Since IDLE is aimed at beginners, it tries harder to avoid letting users quit accidentally.  (Note that SystemExit in code will not exit IDLE.)

quit() and exit() should not be used in code.  They may be NameErrors, or, as described above, the exact effect may depend on the environment.